# getting issue while writing stored data in a variable to csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, formatting, export-to-csv

Example:
 I'm writing this data to a csv file:

```
data = 'Fiber är beställd till adressen. Tjänsterna kan du beställa när installationen är färdig.'
```

**I've write this code to do this:**

```
with open('test.csv','a',encoding='utf-8',newline='') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(data)
```

When this code runs it gives the output as follows:
[Here's the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USLog.png)

This program is writing each letter separately but i want to write the whole text variable into single cell and then move to the next row for writing next variable's data into the new cell. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`casv.writerow()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) accepts an iterable as the row. In this case it interprets the string as an iterable and its characters as respective items for each field. If you want to write the string in one field you can put it in an iterable like tuple.

```
writer.writerow((data,))
```

Or you can split the data with the intended delimiter:

```
writer.writerow(data.split(','))
```